# Can I grep two files against each other?

Tags: arch-linux, grep

I want to grep file A for every phrase in file B, where a phrase is a string of words of length X. Ideally, it would be an approximate grep, like agrep. Is there a way to do that using command-line tools?

Comment: `grep` has `-f` option which allows you to use patterns from a file, with one pattern per line. Can't really tell from your question if that works for you.

Comment: It sounds like you may just want to `diff` the files

Comment: `agrep: approximate matching is not supported with -f option`

Comment: @Dave, is there a way to run diff to only show similarities, not differences?

Comment: @Jon using the `line-formatting` options it is: `diff file1 file2 --old-line-format='' --new-line-format='' --unchanged-line-format='%L'` I'll make an answer to explain it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could try something like:

```
x=3
B_words=($(<B))
A_words=($(<A))
A="$A_words"

setopt extendedglob
for ((i = 1; i<=$#B_words - x + 1; i++)) {
  phrase=$B_words[i,i+x-1]
  [[ " $A " = (#a2)*" $phrase "* ]] && printf '%s\n' $phrase
}
```

Which should give you the sequences of 3 words of file B that are also found in file A (allowing 2 errors with `(#a2)`).

For instance, if `A` is your question and `B` is the sentence above, I get:

```
of 3 words
3 words of
in file A
```

Or if you want to see what was matched in file `A`:

```
for ((i = 1; i<=$#B_words - x + 1; i++)) {
  phrase=$B_words[i,i+x-1]
  [[ " $A " = (#a2)(#b)*" "($phrase)" "* ]] &&
    printf '%s\n' "$phrase ($match[1])"
}
```

which gives:

```
of 3 words (of words)
3 words of (words of)
in file A (in file B,)
```

*words* here are defined as sequences of non-IFS characters which with the default value of $IFS is any character other than space, tab, newline and nul.

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff so long as you're concerned with whole lines:

```
diff file1 file2 --old-line-format='' --new-line-format='' --unchanged-line-format='%L'
```

The `old-line-format` refers to lines only in the first file, the format is blank to leave them out.

The `new-line-format` refers to lines only in the second file, the format is blank to leave them out.

The `unchanged-line-format` refers to lines in both files, and the format `'%L'` is to print out the line including its line break.

You can see more about the formatting of diff output here: http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Formats.html

Answer (score -1):

Easy, just run `cat A | grep -f B` for patterna or simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< $(cat "$1")

read -ra ADDR2 <<< $(cat "$2")

for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do

    for n in "${ADDR2[@]}"; do

    if [[ "$i" -eq "$n" ]]; then

        echo $n

    fi

    done

done
```

and run it with files as parameters `./scritp.sh A B`

Comment: As @munircontractor is saying above, grep -f takes file of patterns, with one pattern per line. But my file B doesn't have one pattern per line--it's just a regular text file (a book), and so a phrase can appear anywhere in the line.

Comment: Unfortunately, `grep` doesn't do approximate matching and  `agrep` supports `-f` but then can't do approximate matching. Its  regexp support is also quite limited so that using `agrep 'foo|bar|...longregexp'` is generally not an option.

Comment: added a script solution for `space` separated words. if u use different separator - change the `IFS` value to match it.